# Change spellchecker language used in textarea on IPAD

Tags: html, ipad, textarea, spell-checking

Can we change the spellchecker language using plain HTML?

Or does it use the device settings and Safari Mobile settings (language)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You can set the `lang` attribute on the input element, say `<input lang=de>`, but HTML5 drafts do not even suggest that this would affect the spellchecking, and as far as I see, it does not affect it. The selection of the language is to be made by the user, via the browser’s user interface, in a browser-dependent manner.